# Listview inside Scroll view is not clickable

Tags: android, xamarin

I have 2 views. 
1)MyMenuRestaurent.axml 2) ImageAndSubTitle.axml

code for MyMenuRestaurent.axml

```
<LinearLayout>
 <ListView>
 </ListView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Code For Image And Sub Title

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightgray">
  <ScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff81d4fa">
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="10dip">
      </LinearLayout>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/Text1"
          android:text="Demo Item Name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:textSize="20dip" />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/Text2"
          android:text="Demo Price"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="14dip"
          android:textColor="@color/blue" />
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

I have listview clickable. when click on one item detail of individual item is opened. but if i add scroll view (click) is not working. because scroll view block click on element. i want to make click on item along with scroll view.

Comment: Have you solved  your problem?

Comment: unfortunatley no!

Comment: So, what's the problem? Could you please elaborate it so that I can help you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in `LinearLayout`, it may looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightgray"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom listview you must have an adaptor and you'll passing a custom view for it. So put the `onClickListener` on the parent layout of the custom view in your adaptor it will mimic the `onItemClickListener` of the listview.

Let this is your custom view for listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="120dp"
          >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:src="@drawable/homeopathy"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:tint="#7b000000"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-67dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="This is a sample text"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    />

  </LinearLayout>
```

and in the adaptor

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);

    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    list= data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(list.getTitle());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(list.getImage());

    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    linLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do what you want to do
        }
    });


    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Any Demo? or Sample Code?

Answer (score 0):

> because scroll view block click on element. i want to make click on item along with scroll view.

You could write a custom `ListView` and override its [OnInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method to get the Touch event from `ScrollView`.

> Implement this method to intercept all touch screen motion events. This allows you to watch events as they are dispatched to your children, and take ownership of the current gesture at any point.

Code like this :

```
public class InnerListview : ListView
{
  ...

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        switch (ev.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                setParentScrollAble(false);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                setParentScrollAble(true);
                break;
        }
        return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private void setParentScrollAble(bool flag)
    {
        Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(!flag);
    }
}
```

Use this `ListView` in you `.axml` like this :

```
<ListViewInScrollView.InnerListview
     android:id="@+id/lv3"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:background="#ffffff" />
```